# Adding trailingslash for file path in php

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to add a trailing slash in file path. The follow code works fine, but when I add the trailing slash at the end of `subdir`, it generates `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING`.

Please guide me a little bit.

**Good code:**

```
add_post_meta($post_id, '_wow_photo', trailingslashit($uploaddir['subdir']) . $filename);
```

**Code with error:**

```
add_post_meta($post_id, '_wow_photo', ($uploaddir['subdir'])trailingslashit . $filename);
```

Comment: Your non-working code has the function's parameters before the function call. What are you trying to do? Doesn't `trailingslashit` add a trailing slash?

Comment: @andrewsi I guess he wrote it after for that very reason: "trailingslashit() adds a slash - I want a slash there - let's write trailingslashit where I need the slash"

Comment: This looks more like, "when I introduce a syntax error, I get a syntax error"

Comment: @DamienPirsy - that's pretty much what I got, too; but as I understand it, `trailingslashit($uploaddir['subdir'])` already puts a slash at the end of its output. Admittedly, I'm a little slow today, as the coffee machine is out of commission....

Comment: No, it doesn't put slash at the end, but at the start of path.

Comment: Not according to the documentation: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/trailingslashit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update** There is no need for the call to your function just simply append the / to your string

```
add_post_meta($post_id, '_wow_photo', ($uploaddir['subdir']).'/'. $filename);
```

Comment: what's the problem with `'/'` ? Why the backslash?

Comment: Ah I am wrong with this, its a second forward slash. Im updating.

Comment: when you append a slash onto a string php reads the '/' as an escape character.

Comment: **NO, it doesn't**. You're getting confused with the backslash: `'\'` <-- this nedds escaping (`'\\'`), `'/'` <-- this, doesn't

Comment: Your correct. A single Slash should work just fine. Theres no need for the call to your function just append a single slash. Good catch @DamienPirsy

Comment: @inner_class7 Yes, single slash is the right solution. Thank you :)